# Geoprocessing Service on ArcGIS Server to Export File

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arctoolbox, geoprocessing-service

**ArcGIS Server /**
**Geoprocessing Question**

I have a geoprocessing service that will perform a selection on a layer based on a provided expression.  I would like to output the result as a csv file (or other type of file) and have it output to the browser for the user to download.  Currently, i can save the output to a scratch directory on the server but I want to return it back to the user.  This is similar to the clip/zip/ship process.  How do I run a process and return a file back to the client?

Does anybody have a detailed workflow or example to point me to?

Comment: I've got an application that does this by creating a servlet to accept the initial request, then the servlet tasks the job with a local output file, and once the GP job completes, then alters the `HttpServletResponse` with a ContentType and Header which encourages the browser to save it.

Comment: Is your question: how do I write the Python code to do this workflow? If so, read this: https://geonet.esri.com/message/381403#381403  Or is it, how do I write JavaScript code?

Comment: KHibma, your response and post ultimately led to a solution.  Thank You.